# 2D Mass Spring System - Where does $m_3$ go to?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

I am struggling to frame proper equations for the following two-dimensional mass spring System:

## 1D Model

Basics first:
I started with a simple one-dimensional mass-spring System to model something like a Crash of two rail vehicles:

[image: 1D Mass Spring System]

The two masses m1 and m2 are the Center of Gravities of the two rail vehicles, while the two springs with their corresponding stiffnesses k1 and k2 model the differences in stiffness of the two colliding wagons. 
By assuming the mass m3 to be 0, the displacement $S_{M}$ of m3 can be calculated as:

$$
S_{M}=\frac{k_{1}S_{1}+k_{2}S_{2}}{k_{1}+k_{2}}
$$

## 2D Model

Now I was wondering how this model applies to oblique Scenarios and whether we could consider longitudinal and lateral stiffnesses rather than the 1D springs.
[image]

So I split the springs from the 1D model into two springs with separate stiffnesses k1_long, k1_lat, k2_long and k2_lat. 
The question is now, how the red m3 moves, based on the Forces applied to it through the 4 springs.

My first Approach would have been to decompose the Forces into their x and y components but then I Need to decompose a spring into a x_component spring and a y_component spring, of which I don't know the stiffnesses.

Do you see a possibility to get the movement of m3 (=Connection Point of two wagons) based on the known movements of the other masses and the stiffnesses of the springs?

Comment: Is this a statics problem, a dynamics problem, or a vibration problem?

Comment: It's a dynamic Problem, as the two wagons Keep moving over time

Comment: So something with zero mass will have infinite acceleration if there is a net force applied to it. So if $m_3$ is small compared to the forces applied you are going to get garbage or unstable results.

Comment: So are the two $m_1$ and two $m_2$ masses connected somehow? It is not clear from the diagram at all. Are lat/long always perpendicular or when $m_3$ moves they change the angle between them?

Comment: Imagine two cars colliding. $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ are the two cars, while m3 is the Point they touch each other. 
The angle between $k_{Long}$ and $k_{lat}$ is always 90°. The angle between the two cars can Change over time

In the 1D example, Setting the mass $m_{3}$ to Zero was a proper trick to determine the "Center of collision" which might move depending on the masses and stiffnesses of the two rail vehicles

Comment: So the diagram is all wrong, because it shows two masses $m_1$ and two masses $m_2$ when in reality you have one of each. Also what is missing is the mass moment of inertia of each car.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I might have to split the original masses $m_{1}$ and $m_{2}$ into two parts (like $m_{1a}$, $m_{1b}$) what brings up the next question, of how I would split $m_{1}$ into two $m_{1a} + m_{1b} = m_{1}$.
Regarding the mass moment of inertia I don't get your Point. Both vehicles are moving linearly

Comment: I updated my description and added a Image to clarify the Situation. How must the masses be Chosen, what do you think?

Comment: Are you considering the centers of the vehicles "stuck" on a linear path, or can the cars bounce off each other after the impact?

Comment: The movement starts on a linear path but as soon as the cars interact, I want to use the acting Forces to update the path iteratively timestep by timestep. 
The Point is, that the cars can intrude into each other - what I want to model too. Do you know any examples like this, where one mass is held by multiple springs from various angles?

Comment: What you are asking for is not a simple force problem. You would have to model the behavior of the crumpling cars with continuum mechanics. There are programs for that, but it takes years to develop them and the learning curve us very steep. No mass-spring model is going to give you even remotely useful results.

Comment: I agree with CuriousOne. The behavior you want only comes with a non-linear spring with plastic deformation and damping. In a simulation sense you need to define a common normal and apply the contact forces along this direction.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your assessment. If the Problem would be only about the 5 masses connected by springs - what would be your Approach for this?

Comment: If you just have masses something has to force the springs out of equilibrium. Like a direction of motion, or preload on the springs. Those are two different problems.

Comment: well, the two wagons have mass, speed and direction. With $F = S * k$, where k is the stiffness and S is the displacement of the spring, the forces can be determined. 
Let's assume the moving direction of the two wagons is parallel to their longitudinal axis - then the distance travelled by the cars from last timestep to the current timestep multiplied by the springs stiffnesses leads to the two forces along the longitudinal springs. 
The lateral springs experience forces only because of the opponent cars. So the previously calculated forces must be split into their local x- and y components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each side of the contact point has a 2×2 stiffness matrix defined in local (body) coordinates

$$ \begin{align} {\bf k}_1^{\rm body} & = 
\begin{vmatrix} k_1^{\rm long} & 0 \\ 0 & k_1^{\rm lat}
\end{vmatrix} & {\bf k}_2^{\rm body} & = 
\begin{vmatrix} k_2^{\rm long} & 0 \\ 0 & k_2^{\rm lat}
\end{vmatrix} \end{align}$$

Now if each body has a 2×2 orientation (rotation) matrix defined by the angles $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ then

$$ \begin{align} {\bf R}_1 &= \begin{vmatrix} \cos\psi_1 & -\sin\psi_1 \\ \sin\psi_1 & \cos\psi_1 \end{vmatrix} & {\bf R}_2 &= \begin{vmatrix} \cos\psi_2 & -\sin\psi_2 \\ \sin\psi_2 & \cos\psi_2 \end{vmatrix} \end{align} $$

The effective 2×2 stiffness (symmetric) matrix in world coordinates is calculated with

$$ {\bf k} = {\bf R}_1 {\bf k}_1^{\rm body} {\bf R}_1^\intercal +{\bf R}_2 {\bf k}_2^{\rm body} {\bf R}_2^\intercal = \begin{vmatrix} k_{xx} & k_{xy} \\ k_{xy} & k_{yy} \end{vmatrix}$$ where $\Box^\intercal$ is the matrix transpose.

What you are looking for is the direction of minimum and maximum stiffness (which are 90°) apart where the contact point would try to move towards. This is found by finding the angle $\varphi$ which causes

$$\begin{vmatrix} \cos\varphi & \sin\varphi \\ -\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} k_{xx} & k_{xy} \\ k_{xy} & k_{yy} \end{vmatrix} \begin{vmatrix} \cos\varphi & -\sin\varphi \\ \sin\varphi & \cos\varphi \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} k_{A} & 0 \\ 0 & k_{B} \end{vmatrix} $$

The solution is $$\varphi = \frac{1}{2} \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{2 k_{xy}}{k_{xx}-k_{yy}} \right ) $$

In addition, every integer $i$ multiple offset $\varphi+i \frac{\pi}{2}$ is also a solution.

Comment: Hi ja72,
thank you very much for this comprehensive answer. I have a few question to go ahead:
- I was not aware that the stiffnesses in world cosy can be calculated like shown by you. I wonder why a simple rotation properly splits a given local stiffness into it's world x- and y-components. Furthermore I don't understand why the two sides for k1 and k2 get combined by adding them. To refer to the 1D example - if both, k1 and k2 were 1,then the total stiffness should be 1 and not 1+1=2, shouldn't it?
- What do you mean by minimum/maximum stiffness ?
- Is $\varphi$ the angle of the movement?

Comment: The rotation of a stiffness matrix can be interpreted as moving displacements from world coordinates to local coordinates applying the body stiffness and then converting back to world coordinates. Hence the $K = R K_{body} R^\intercal$ transformation. (search congruent transformation)

Comment: Stiffness matrices are linear and when expressed in the same coordinates are subject to the principle of superposition (and hence can be added directly). In the 1D case the two springs on the left and right can be added together because they act in the same direction. The stiffness would be 1+1=2 since the force from _each_ spring is felt by $m_3$. The springs are considered "in parallel" actually because they share displacement.

Comment: Thank you very much @ja72,
you helped me a lot with that problem. Can you please give me a little more explanation on the $k_{A}$ and $k_{B}$ as well as the $\varphi$ - I am not completely sure, whether I got what they are?

Comment: if $k_A>k_B$ then $\varphi$ is the direction of maximum stiffness and if $k_A<k_B$ it is the direction of minimum stiffness. The values of $k_A$ and $k_B$ are the extrema (minimum maximum) one would feel if pushed along at an oblique angle. When the oblique angle equals $\varphi$ the effective stiffness will be either the minimum possible, or the maximum possible.

Comment: I have to note that the end result of any stiffness matrix $\mathbf{k}$ is to formulate the force displacement equations $\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{k} \mathbf{\delta}$ in statics or dynamics, where $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{\delta}$ are force and displacement vectors defined _on the same coordinate orientation_.